# python: How to convert function to lambda expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I have the following function that converts a list into a dict.

```
def convert2Dict(item_list):
    d = {}
    for name in item_list:
       d.setdefault(name,0)
       d[name] += 1
    return (d)
```

When I pass a list like:

```
 takeOff_Airport = convert2Dict(takeOff_Airport)
```

I get a dict like:

```
{'LPPD': 4, 'DAAE': 1, 'EDDH': 16, ...... }
```

If I try to construct a map function like:

```
list(map(convert2Dict, takeOff_Airport))
```

I get:

```
[{'L': 1, 'P': 2, 'D': 1}, {'D': 1, 'A': 2, 'E': 1}, ....}
```

Which instead of iterating word by word is doing it character by character.

Any idea how to change it?

Comment: It looks like your `convert2Dict` function might be better replaced by [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with lambda. A lambda function can't do anything that a `def` function can't do.

Comment: Throws an error due to other sections in the code, needs to be as it's presented.

Comment: What does lambda have to do with the question?

Comment: You also haven't provided a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
list(map(convert2Dict, takeOff_Airport))
```

you are essentially performing

```
result = []
for key in takeOff_Airpot:
    result.append(covert2Dict(key))
```

that is, you are applying the `covert2Dict` function to each *key* in the dictionary `covert2Dict`, and then collecting all of the results into a list.

If you want your function to operate on `takeOff_Airport` itself, simply pass it directly as an argument. You only need to use `map` or its relatives if you want to perform some action on each element on an iterable.

Comment: Thanks, now I see it.